# implement tableview to show the data of database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am making a small iPhone application in which I have implemented the database concept which is used to store name, contact no, email id. I Want that whenever I user save any contact It get displayed on table view. In **-(IBAction)retriveall:(id)sender** action I am retriving all the data from database and storing it into array. Now I want to display all the data in tableview.

How can I do this? Please help me.

```
-(IBAction)retriveall:(id)sender
{
    [self retrive2];
    for (int i =0; i< [namearray count]; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Name is:%@",[namearray objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSLog(@"Password is:%@",[passarray objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}



-(IBAction)retrive:(id)sender
{
    [self retrive1];
    two.text = databasecolorvalue;
    UIAlertView  *favAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Retrived" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];        
    [favAlert show];
    [favAlert release]; 
}

-(void)retrive1
{

    databaseName = @"med.sqlite";

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    @try {

        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

            const char *sqlStatement="select pswd from Login where username = ? ";
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
                // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [one.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                    databasecolorvalue  =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)];

                }

            }
            // Release the compiled statement from memory
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    @catch (NSException * ex) {
        @throw ex;
    }
    @finally {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare an mutable array as an instance variable something like,

```
NSMutableArray * colors;
```

Initialize it in the `viewDidLoad` method and later alter your `retrive1` method to add to the colors array.

```
-(void)retrive1
{
    /* Clearing existing values for newer ones */
    [colors removeAllObjects]

    /* Get database path */

    @try {
          [..]
                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) { 
                    [colors addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)]];
                }

          [..]
    }
    @catch (NSException * ex) { @throw ex; }
    @finally { }
}
```

And you'll have to implement the rest of the table view methods in the usual manner using the array as the source.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create object with all data and implementation of UITableViewDataSource protocol  for table view and set it in TableView property dataSource. After you havecall UITableView method 
`-(void)reloadData;`